# Assign sed result to a variable

Tags: bash, sed

I have a sed command and I would like to assign the result to a variable.
My command is:

```
sed -n 's/^Release:\s*\(.*\){?dist}/\1/p' file.spec
```

And I tried

```
var = $(sed -n 's/^Release:\s*\(.*\){?dist}/\1/p' file.spec)
```

But then i have the following error:

> unary operator expected

Comment: While your syntax error has already been spotted, it would be interesting to know why you get that error message here. Have you got `var` aliased to `test` or something like that? What do you get when you run that same command after `set -x`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the spaces around `=`. Otherwise, bash reads your command line as "run `var` with parameters `=` and the output of `sed`".